# Enabling JMX remote agent on Java9

Tags: jmx, java, java-9

I am trying to run a simple application with the JMX remote agent enabled.
While it runs perfectly on older VM's, it fails on Java9 VM.

> $ java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote Hello
>   Error: Config file not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/conf/management/management.properties
>
> $ java -version
>   openjdk version "9-Debian"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Debian+0-9b149-1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Debian+0-9b149-1, mixed mode)

Ho can I fix that?

Moshe

Comment: can you provide a stack trace or your code that is attempting to use the JMX remote agent?  The error is suspicious becuase `$JAVA_HOME/conf/management/management.properties` does exist in OpenJDK 9.

Comment: In addition, 9-Debian+0-9b149-1 looks fishy. Is this really jdk-9+149 from late 2016? JDK 9 is closed to GA candidate, the current build is jdk-9+180.

Comment: The JVM may simply be broken.  This is basically untested software.

Comment: SOLVED. I tried to use the latest docker image from java:openjdk-9 and didn't notice it's 7 months old. switching to the up-to-date openjdk:9-jdk (openjdk:9-b179-jdk) solved the problem. Thanks.